# Android Studio wrong calculate basic

Tags: android-studio-2.0

Today, I am implement a basic calculation in AS and here is results: https://www.flickr.com/photos/139045967@N03/26159345381/in/dateposted-public/

```
1.0f - 16.0f/100 = 0.84000003; // is right ?
```

I am use MAC with AS 2.1 preview 5. Anyone help me this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

float uses 24-bit for the significant digits. Which means it has approximately 7 digits of precision.

1234567
0.8400000 3

It has nothing to do with Android Studio.

Comment: Nothing, **1 - 0.16 = 0.84000003**. What is nothing ? Right or wrong, it is a basic calculation.

Comment: With nothing, I mean that the problem is not specific to Android Studio. Same thing happens i Eclipse.